# Log cell value on specific time intervals

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

The function `=GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:GOOG","PRICE")` fetches the realtime price in Google Sheets. So if it is required to log the value of the above function **every 15 minutes** and reset the log at midnight, is there any way to do so?
Mainly I have to log value of a derived field which uses value of this function.

[Required format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUToR.png)

| TIME (in 24h format) | Price |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution. Put a trigger (15mn) on 'periodic'

```
function activate(x) {
  return x
}
function periodic(){
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  var der=sh.getLastRow()+1
  sh.getRange('A'+der).setValue(new Date())
  sh.getRange('B'+der).setValue(sh.getRange('A2').getValue())
  sh.getRange('B1').setValue(!sh.getRange('B1').getValue())
}
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QM7uI1xsJaCDkyEZ1UvE3knc00gFlgt_BItJQRb9M70/copy

Comment: Thanks, Mike for introducing me to Apps Script but I didn't get what is the last line doing?

`sh.getRange('B1').setValue(!sh.getRange('B1').getValue())`

Its  showing a like a radio button in the cell B1.
Also what is the `function activate (x)` doing?

Comment: How it works : first, the script copy the last value, and (this is the main action) change the value of the ckeck-box (true/false). By this mean, it re-activates the function of B4 which includes the vlaue of the check-box, even if this value has no influence of the result. Finally, by virtually changing the value "PRICE", the GOOGLEFINANCE function is also reactivated.